# Is there an equivalent to C's *(unsigned int*)(char) = 123 in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, c

I'm dealing with some C source code I'm trying to convert over to Javascript, I've hit a snag at this line

```
char ddata[512];
*(unsigned int*)(ddata+0)=123;
*(unsigned int*)(ddata+4)=add-8;
memset(ddata+8,0,add-8);
```

I'm not sure exactly what is happening here, I understand they're casting the char to an unsigned int, but what is the `ddata+0` and stuff doing here? Thanks.

Comment: That code exposes undefined behavior, just so that you know. It violates the strict-aliasing rule.

Comment: @cad Thanks for the heads up, I'm not too familiar with C, I know the basics and what not but this is a bit above my level, if I could just figure out the Javascript way to write that out I could probably improve it.

Comment: It depends on how your `ddata` array is defined in Javascript.

Comment: I don't know the JavaScript way but C and JavaScript are distinct languages. How will knowing how to write this in JavaScript help you?

Comment: @MOehm I'm trying to mimic it as closely as possible, just for the porting, but I've just done `var data = new Array(512);`

Comment: @cad I just need to know what they're trying to accomplish in C so that I can write it in JS, it's just I'm very basic when it comes to C. I understand they're very different

Comment: I think chqrlie has it: It is an object with `add - 8` bytes of data. A possible js representation might be an object, eg: `{id: 123, len: 4, data[0, 0, 0, 0]}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't say.

That's because the behaviour on casting a `char*` to an `unsigned*` is *undefined* **unless** the pointer started off as an `unsigned*`, which, in your case it didn't.

`ddata + 0` is equivalent to `ddata`.

`ddata + 4` is equivalent to `&ddata[4]`, i.e. the address of the 5th element of the array.

For what it's worth, it looks like the C programmer is attempting to serialise a couple of `unsigned` literals into a byte array. But the code is a mess; aside from what I've already said they appear to be assuming that an `unsigned` occupies 4 bytes, which is not necessarily the case.

Comment: So would `ddata+0 = 123;` turn all of ddata into `123`?

Comment: @Datsik That would set the first element of the char array ddata to 123 in integer value, which translates to 'S' in ascii format.

Comment: @Datsik: not on its own. You need to *dereference* the pointer, which is what `*` is attempting to do. But be careful, that C code is malformed.

Comment: @Bathsheba malformed.. hahaha.. Thanks! I'mm kar this as an answer unless somebody comes up with a JS way to write this out. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The code fragment is storing a record id (`123`) as 4 byte integer in the first 4 bytes of a `char` buffer `ddata`. It then stores a length (`add-8`) in the following 4 bytes and finally initializes the following `add-8` bytes to `0`.

Translating this to javascript can be done in different ways, but probably not by constructing a string with the same contents.  The reason is strings a not byte buffers in javascript, they contain unicode code points, so writing the string to storage might perform some unwanted conversions.

The best solution depends on your actual target platform, where byte arrays may be available to more closely match the intended semantics of your C code.

Note that the above code is not portable and has undefined behavior for various reasons, notably because `ddata` might not be properly aligned to be used as the address to store an `unsigned int` via the cast `*(unsigned int*)ddata = 123;`, because it assumes `int` to be 4 bytes and because it relies on unspecified byte ordering.

On the Redhat linux box it probably works as expected, and the same C code would probably perform correctly on MacOS, that uses the same Intel architecture with little endian ordering. How best to translate this to Javascript requires more context and specifications.

In the mean time, the code would best be rewritten this way:

```
unsigned char ddata[512];
if (add <= 512) {
    ddata[0] = 123;
    ddata[1] = 0;
    ddata[2] = 0;
    ddata[3] = 0;
    ddata[4] = ((add-8) >> 0) & 255;
    ddata[5] = ((add-8) >> 8) & 255;
    ddata[6] = ((add-8) >> 16) & 255;
    ddata[7] = ((add-8) >> 24) & 255;
    memset(ddata + 8, 0, add - 8);
}
```

Comment: Assuming, of course, that `unsigned int` is four bytes on the platform in question.

Comment: It will be developed on OS X but ran in production on Redhat

Comment: Also I can use byte Buffers in Node.js https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html if that's what you're referring to

Comment: @Datsik: OK, that's what I was referring to.  I rewrote the C code to make the conversion into javascript much simpler.  `memset` just sets part of the buffer to 0.

Comment: @chqrlie Which part of the buffer to zero?

Comment: @Datsik: As I explain in the answer, `memset` sets `add-8` bytes starting at the 9th byte of the buffer to the value `0`.  There is probably more code below the fragment you posted that modifies this part of the buffer and writes it to disk or otherwise transmits it somewhere.